# how to set fit image to individual tab in tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to set image which must be fit to the tab
in my tabhost which have 2 tabs
this is my code

```
tab =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
tab.setup();
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tab.newTabSpec("tag1");
spec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginpic));
spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
tab.addTab(spec);

spec = tab.newTabSpec("tag2");
spec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.signuppic));
spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
tab.addTab(spec);
```

the image is small and didn't fill the full tab

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Drawable loginpic= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginpic);
StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
selector.addState(new int[0], selectedIcon);
spec.setIndicator("Tab 1", selector);
```

Comment: the same result :/